# Dynamic array of pointers to struct throws SIGSEGV on member variable assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic-arrays

I'm quite sure this a simple issue, but I am trying to create a data structure that implements a dynamic array of structs.

Each struct will implement a linked list.

So I think that I want an array of pointers, which will point to the head of each list. For some reason, assigning method variables gives me a seg fault. I would love a little explanation  of what I am doing wrong if you could. THANKS!

Oh, also, all of this is inside a class called Cache, so that is why there are some variables that don't appear to be defined, but I assure you they are. The program seg faults on indexes[i]->next = NULL; and the similar lines below that one.

```
        typedef struct setNode {
    char valid, dirty;
    unsigned int tag;
    setNode *next;
    Cache *nextCache;

} set;
    set **indexes;

    arrayLength = cache_size / block_size;

    indexes = new setNode *[arrayLength];

    set *temp;

    //Step through the array. The array is full of pointers to "Dummy Nodes"
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        indexes[i]->next = NULL;
        indexes[i]->valid = 0;
        indexes[i]->dirty = 0;
        indexes[i]->tag = 0;
        //create empty linked list for each tag spot (One for direct mapped. etc...)

         for(size_t i = 0; i < associativity; i++)
         {
         temp = indexes[i];
         temp->next = new setNode;
         temp = temp->next;
         temp->next = NULL;
         temp->valid = 0;
         temp->dirty = 0;
         temp->tag = 0;
         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexes` is an array of pointers to `set` objects, but they are uninitialized. They don't point to  actual `set` objects, but merely to random memory locations. Trying to write to random memory is the very essence of the segmentation violation.

Before using your pointers, you need to allocate `set` objects and make the pointers point to them -- i.e.,

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    indexes[i] = new set;
    indexes[i]->next = NULL;
    indexes[i]->valid = 0;
    ...
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense... I added indexes[i] = new set; at the top of the for loop and now it works. Thanks! Silly me, I didn't realize you need to initialize structs as well as classes, but since the array just has pointers, it makes sense.